# map js url not loading magento2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, mapping

we have a site that was running fine, we just move site to new instance and got an error. All js file's map urls, that we define in require-config.js file not loading on frontend.

Like, we define -

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
                customjs : 'Magento_Theme/js/custom'
            }

        }
};
```

on frontend,site making url -  http://localhost/Mysite/pub/static/frontend/Magento/Commerce/en_US/customjs.js

And giving error

> File Not Found Error

To make it work, I removed pub/static/all_files and re-run the static-content deploy command, cache flush, re-index multiple times, but non making effect.

Please help me to solve it. 
Thanks

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: thx for ur answer, But what is the issue with mine declaration of file path. This is just an example,  we have around 10more files that are not loading. Please suggest any common solution........

Answer (score 0):

you can update your code this way

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
                customjs : 'Magento_Theme/js/customjs'
            }

        }
};
```

after re-run the static-content deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```